# Cant copy a file in Linux: cp: target '/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi' is not a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-transfer, cp, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18. I want to copy two files in a directory from the desktop to the following directory: `home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi`

I executed this command:

```
~/Desktop$ sudo cp servers-certs/cert1.pem servers-certs/cert2.pem /home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi
```

I get this error:

```
cp: target '/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi' is not a directory
```

I tried to navigate manually through the GUI. But when I enter the \home\me I can't find the `.local` directory.

My questions:

1) How to copy the two files from the desktop directory I specified to the other directory?

2) Why I can not see `.local` directory? how can I see it?

Answer (score 0):

The error
    cp: target '/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi' is not a directory
means there is no directory /home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi, you need to make it, from the terminal:

```
cd /home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages   
mkdir certifi
```

this is assuming the directory /home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages exists
then do you cp command again

The reason you don see the .local is because files and direcories starting with a dot are hidden, you can make them visible in nautilis by clicking the "View" menu and then click on the "Hidden Files" option.

Comment: I am sure there is a directory with that name. However, I navigated to it using the GUI after showing the hidden directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the target was `/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi` as you claim, `cp` would be complaining about it literally (if ever). It complains about `/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi` instead. Note this is a *different* path. Two explanations:

1. Either you put a space between `/home/me` and `/.local/lib/…` you didn't want to put (highly probable); run `cp` with the right target path.
2. Or there really is a space after `me`, the directory name is `"me "` (uncommon but still technically possible); in this case you should quote the whole target:

   ```
   "/home/me /.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi"
   ```

Normally you cannot see `.local` because objects starting with `.` (dot) are "hidden". With `ls` you need `-a` option. Many GUI tools react to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (dot), this toggles the visibility of such objects.

Comment: In Ubuntu, it's `Ctrl-h` which toggles showing hidden files, both in file manager and application file dialogues.